Calendar Events Not Reaching Laravel Controller or Database
I'm trying to save events created in a Calendar to my database using Laravel. I have a route, controller, and AJAX request set up, but the event data doesn't seem to be reaching the controller or getting saved in the database.
here is my code
my route 

Route::post('/save-calender-event-endpoint', [CalenderController::class, 'saveEvent']) -> name('save-calender-event-endpoint');

my controller

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\CalenderEvent;

class CalenderController extends Controller
{
  public function saveEvent(Request $request) {

  print_r("hellow from calander controller");

    $request->validate([
        'event_name' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'Start_time' => 'required|date|before:End_time',
        'End_time' =>   'required|date|after:Start_time',
        'Category' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'event_postedby' => 'required|string|max:255',
       
    ]);

 try {
    $event = CalenderEvent::create([
        'event_name' => $request->event_name,
        'Start_time' => $request->Start_time,
        'End_time' => $request->End_time,
        'Category' => $request->Category,
        'event_postedby' => $request->event_postedby,
       
    ]);

    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'event' => $event],201);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed to save event.'], 500);
}
  }
}


Javascript 

function convertTo12HourFormat(time24) {
    // Assuming input is in HH:mm format, split the time into hours and minutes
    const [hours, minutes] = time24.split(':');

    // Create a new Date object based on the hours and minutes
    const date = new Date();
    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);

    // Use toLocaleTimeString to convert the time to 12-hour format
    const options = { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true };
    const time12 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options);

    return time12;
}


! function(e) {
    "use strict";
    var t = function() {
        this.$body = e("body"), this.$modal = e("#event-modal"), this.$event = "#external-events div.external-event", this.$calendar = e("#calendar"), this.$saveCategoryBtn = e(".save-category"), this.$categoryForm = e("#add-category form"), this.$extEvents = e("#external-events"), this.$calendarObj = null
    };
    t.prototype.onDrop = function(t, n) {
        var a = t.data("eventObject"),
            o = t.attr("data-class"),
            i = e.extend({}, a);
        i.start = n, o && (i.className = [o]), this.$calendar.fullCalendar("renderEvent", i, !0), e("#drop-remove").is(":checked") && t.remove()
    }, t.prototype.onEventClick = function(t, n, a) {
        var o = this,
            i = e("<form></form>");

        i.append("<label>Change event name</label>"),
        i.append("<div class='input-group'><input class='form-control' type=text value='" + t.title + "' /><span class='input-group-btn'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Save</button></span></div>"), 
      
        i.append("<label>Category</label>");
        i.append("<div class='form-group'><select class='form-control' name='category'></select></div>");
    
        // Populate the category dropdown
        var categorySelect = i.find("select[name='category']");
        categorySelect
            .append("<option value='bg-danger'>Red</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-success'>Green</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-dark'>Dark</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-primary'>Blue</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-pink'>Teal</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-info'>Mint</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-warning'>Yellow</option>");
    
        // Pre-select the event's category based on the event's className (category)
        categorySelect.val(t.className);  // Assuming className stores the category like bg-danger


    // Start time input (using a date-time picker or plain text input)
    i.append("<label>Start time</label>");
    i.append("<input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + moment(t.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A') + "' />");
    
    // End time input (using a date-time picker or plain text input)
    i.append("<label>End time</label>");
    i.append("<input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + moment(t.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A') + "' />");


        o.$modal.modal({
            backdrop: "static"
        }),
        
        o.$modal.find(".delete-event").show().end().find(".save-event").hide().end().find(".modal-body").empty().prepend(i).end().find(".delete-event").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
            o.$calendarObj.fullCalendar("removeEvents", function(e) {
                return e._id == t._id
            }), o.$modal.modal("hide")
        }), o.$modal.find("form").on("submit", function() {
            return t.title = i.find("input[type=text]").val(), o.$calendarObj.fullCalendar("updateEvent", t), o.$modal.modal("hide"), !1
        })
    }, t.prototype.onSelect = function(t, n, a) {
        var o = this;
        o.$modal.modal({
            backdrop: "static"
        });
        var i = e("<form></form>");
        i.append("<div class='row'></div>"),
        i.find(".row")
        .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Event Name</label><input class='form-control' placeholder='Insert Event Name' type='text' name='title'/></div></div>")
        .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Category</label><select class='form-control' name='category'></select></div></div>")
        .find("select[name='category']")
        .append("<option value='bg-danger'>Red</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-success'>Green</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-dark'>Dark</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-primary'>Blue</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-pink'>Teal</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-info'>Mint</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-warning'>Yellow</option></div></div>"), 
        
        i.find(".row")
        .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Start Time</label><input class='form-control' type='datetime-local' name='beginning'/></div></div>")
        .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>End Time</label><input class='form-control' type='datetime-local' name='ending'/></div></div>");
    
        
        
        o.$modal.find(".delete-event").hide().end()
                .find(".save-event").show().end()
                .find(".modal-body").empty().prepend(i).end()
                .find(".save-event").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
            i.submit()
        }), 
        
      /*  o.$modal.find("form").on("submit", function() {
            var e = i.find("input[name='title']").val(),
                a = (i.find("input[name='beginning']").val(),
                     i.find("input[name='ending']").val(), 
                     i.find("select[name='category'] option:checked").val()); */

             o.$modal.find("form").on("submit", function () {
            var e = i.find("input[name='title']").val(); // Event name
            var a = i.find("select[name='category'] option:checked").val(); // Category (color)
            var beginning = i.find("input[name='beginning']").val(); // Start time
            var ending = i.find("input[name='ending']").val(); // End time
           
        

            console.log('Start time:', beginning);  // Check the output here
            console.log('End time:', ending);      // Check the output here
            
            if (!beginning || !ending) {
                alert("Please select valid start and end times.");
                return false;
            }
        
            // Ensure the end time is after the start time
            if (new Date(ending) <= new Date(beginning)) {
                alert("End time must be after the start time.");
                return false;
            }

            //send data through AJAX

            
            
           // Save changes to event using AJAX
    o.$modal.find(".save-event").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
        // Gather event data
        var eventData = {
            event_name: i.find("input[name='title']").val(),
            category: i.find("select[name='category']").val(),
            start_time: moment(i.find("input[name='start_time']").val(), 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A').toISOString(),  // Convert to ISO string
            end_time: moment(i.find("input[name='end_time']").val(), 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A').toISOString(),  // Convert to ISO string
            event_postedby: "default_user" 
        };

        console.log("Save Event button clicked");
        // Display data in an alert (for testing purposes)
        alert("Hello, World! Data sent: \nTitle: " + eventData.title + "\nCategory: " + eventData.category);

        // Send the event data to the server via AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: '/save-calender-event-endpoint',  
            type: 'POST',
            data: eventData,
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    // Event saved successfully
                    alert("Event saved successfully");
                } else {
                    alert("Error saving event: " + response.message);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("An error occurred while saving the event: " + error);
            }
        });
    });
            


              // Extract time (HH:mm) part from the full datetime string
    var startTime24 = beginning.split('T')[1].substring(0, 5); // Extract "HH:mm" from "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"
    var endTime24 = ending.split('T')[1].substring(0, 5); // Extract "HH:mm" from "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"

    // Convert the extracted 24-hour time to 12-hour format
    var startTime = convertTo12HourFormat(startTime24); // 12-hour format with AM/PM
    var endTime = convertTo12HourFormat(endTime24); // 12-hour format with AM/PM

    console.log('Formatted Start time:', startTime);
    console.log('Formatted End time:', endTime);

            return null !== e && 0 != e.length ? (o.$calendarObj.fullCalendar("renderEvent", {
                title: e,
                start: beginning,
                end: ending,
                allDay: false,
                className: a
            }, !0), o.$modal.modal("hide")) : alert("You have to give a title to your event"), !1
        }), o.$calendarObj.fullCalendar("unselect")
    }, t.prototype.enableDrag = function() {
        e(this.$event).each(function() {
            var t = {
                title: e.trim(e(this).text())
            };
            e(this).data("eventObject", t), e(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: !0,
                revertDuration: 0
            })
        })
    }, t.prototype.init = function() {
        this.enableDrag();
        var t = new Date,
            n = (t.getDate(), t.getMonth(), t.getFullYear(), new Date(e.now())),
          
            o = this;
        o.$calendarObj = o.$calendar.fullCalendar({
            slotDuration: "00:15:00",
            minTime: "08:00:00",
            maxTime: "19:00:00",
            defaultView: "month",
            handleWindowResize: !0,
            height: e(window).height() - 100,
            header: {
                left: "prev,next today",
                center: "title",
                right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
            },
            events: [],
            editable: !0,
            droppable: !0,
            eventLimit: !0,
            selectable: !0,
            drop: function(t) {
                o.onDrop(e(this), t)
            },
            select: function(e, t, n) {
                o.onSelect(e, t, n)
            },
            eventClick: function(e, t, n) {
                o.onEventClick(e, t, n)
            }
        }), this.$saveCategoryBtn.on("click", function() {
            var e = o.$categoryForm.find("input[name='category-name']").val(),
                t = o.$categoryForm.find("select[name='category-color']").val();
            null !== e && 0 != e.length && (o.$extEvents.append('<div class="external-event bg-' + t + '" data-class="bg-' + t + '" style="position: relative;"><i class="fa fa-move"></i>' + e + "</div>"), o.enableDrag())
        })
    }, e.CalendarApp = new t, e.CalendarApp.Constructor = t
}(window.jQuery),
function(e) {
    "use strict";
    e.CalendarApp.init()
}(window.jQuery);

the html modal

   <div class="modal fade none-border" id="event-modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add New Event</strong></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-event waves-effect waves-light" >Create event</button>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-event waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


when i click create event i want it to create the event and store it in the database. I notice the print_r statement is not even being reached so I am unsure where i went wrong or what I overlooked . please help

in your controller, you require Category to be present, and you have provided it in your js code, but it is case sensitive and your js code is sending lowercase category. that can be one problem to solve. also check for errors in your browser network and console tabs

@AxissXs thanks for pointing that out
in my console I see
Start time: 2024-12-15T12:40
fullcalendar-init.js:120 End time: 2024-12-15T13:35
fullcalendar-init.js:184 Formatted Start time: 12:40 PM
fullcalendar-init.js:185 Formatted End time: 01:35 PM
when adding the event date and time

i notice after i remove the  o.$modal.find(".save-event").unbind("click").on("click", function() { and the closing tag  });
i get better result that actually point to the error
in the alert message box
hello world ! Data Sent
title: Undefined
category : bg-danger
after closing this
I get another error saying an error occurred while saving the event :unprocessable content
in the console I get 422 (unprocessable content )

error 422 is from your request validation in the controller, have you matched "Category" and "category"? i suggest editing your question and updating it with these checks and errors you see right now in a formatted way, cause it's confusing in an unformatted comment.

@AxissXs thanks for your comment. I managed to solve it. now my other issue is to pull it and have the event being displayed on the calender

here is my controller
public function showEvent()
{
$user = Auth::user();
$events = CalendarEvent::where('user_id', $user->id)->get() ->toArray();
\Log::info('Fetched events: ', $events->toArray());
return response() -> json($events);

}

the route 

Route::get('/calendar-events', [CalendarController::class, 'showEvent'])->name('showEvent');

the js
the js
$.ajax({
    url: '/calendar-events',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(events) {
        console.log(events); 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: events,         
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Could not fetch events!');
    }
});

